# Import SVGs from GraphQL query in React (Gatsby)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, svg, graphql

I have a case studies page, displaying a grid of projects with a background image and an SVG logo. Those come from a WordPress CPT and are displayed in my Gatsby website using GraphQL.

I need to write the SVGs as inline, rather than an `<img>` tag, so I assume I'll need to import them at the top of the file, but I can't find a working solution for this.
My attempt was:

```js
data.allWordpressWpProject.edges.map((svg, i) => {
    import Logo{i} from svg.node.acf.prj_logo.url.localFile.publicURL
})
```

I assume this is quite a common issue, but I can't seem to find a solution anywhere. Can anyone help?

Comment: Could you clarify how GraphQL fits into this?

Comment: It's just the data source returning the array of objects containing the svg files I try to import.

Answer (score 1):

Only as possible step on the way to a solution: I went ahead and sourced the SVG File from the publicURL with:

```js
let SvgObject = await fetch(svg.localFile.publicURL)
  .then(response => response.text())

let stringToHTML = function(str) {
  let parser = new DOMParser();
  let svgTest = parser.parseFromString(str, 'text/html');
  return svgTest.body;
}

const SvgDOMElement = stringToHTML(SvgObject)
```

My struggle here being, that I fail to implement the DOM Element into a component.